# More than one Parent Activity - How to?

Tags: java, android, class, android-manifest, manifest

Helo,

I want to have my app to do a config for different clouds.

So I need for every cloud a unique class. For example this would call the Google Drive class:

```
                    Intent i = new Intent(RecordConfigStep2.this, RecordConfigStep3_GDrive.class);
                    startActivityForResult(i, 1);
```

For a configuration with Dropbox I need:

```
                    Intent i = new Intent(RecordConfigStep2.this, RecordConfigStep3_Dropbox.class);
                    startActivityForResult(i, 1);
```

After the cloud configuration the app should return back to "normal" configuration.

So it should behave like this:

[Class diagramm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qjlO1.png)

In class A the user can choose the cloud.

Then in class B and C the cloud will be configured.

And back to class D the user can do additional app configuration.

What do I need to write in the AndroidManifest.xml file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `Intent`.

From Activity A, send type, say i a String value which shows the type of Cloud like "gdrive", "dropbox" etc.

In Activity B, get the type String, if it equals "gdrive" > Do GDrive Operation else if it equals "dropbox" > Do Dropbox operation...

Similarly, Send your data from B > C > D > E

More info: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent